# Click On Option From MenuStrip Control(tray notification icons)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, system-tray, trayicon

i want do something like:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVKCq.png]

this code opens the tray notification icons window:

```
Dim Shell_TrayWnd As IntPtr = FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", "")
Dim TrayNotifyWnd As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(Shell_TrayWnd, 0, "TrayNotifyWnd", "")
Dim TrayNotifyButtonWnd As IntPtr = FindWindowEx(TrayNotifyWnd, 0, "Button", "")

Dim BM_CLICK As Integer = &HF5
SendMessage(TrayNotifyButtonWnd, BM_CLICK, 0, 0)
```

now i want to do something like:

```
RightMouseClick(SkypetrayIcon)
ClickOnOption(SkypetrayIconMenuHandle,0)
```

how can i do something like that?.
Maybe there is another way to do it(easier way)

Comment: take a look at [this site](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75822/Create-a-System-Tray-Application-in-VB-NET)

Comment: this article is about how to create System Tray Icon to -my- application. i want to click on option of the context of any System Tray icon of any other application.

Comment: Doesn't that mean that you want to put your button in other applications? If windows would allow this it would be a serious security risk. But anyway I can't help you with that. Good luck

Comment: no, just look at this : http://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cngt.png (i want to click on "click me")

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible with "pywinauto" module python

```
from pywinauto import Application

desktop = Application(backend="uia").connect(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")
sys_tray = desktop.window(class_name="Shell_TrayWnd")
taskbar = desktop.taskbar
icon_tray = taskbar.child_window(title="Right-click for context menu") # this is your "click me"
icon_tray.click_input(button="right")
```